# Organizing and archiving activities is not usable enogh

Tags: feature-request

1. The way of searching through my question and answers is messy.
   i.e Why I should supply a search field with data that may be
   corrupted:

   [image]

   I think another UI rather than placing user ID in the search field should be       more usable an robust.
2. Missing per user tagging and customization for his/her bookmarks. I mean, bookmark, for example, question and set under my own tag with my own description which should be searchable too.
3. Missing favoring answers. The favoring is just for questions why not answers too?

Comment: A duplicate for item #2: [*Classification (or equivalent) option for favorited questions*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305448/2751851)

Comment: #2 and #3 are already available; it's called bookmarks or favorites and it's built into pretty much every browser in existence. Why should SO reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to supply the data to the search field. Visiting a user's page populates the search field with the appropriate ID.
2. By "bookmarks" I assume you mean favorites. But favorites are primarily public - despite the [privacy implications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94826/246570) - and using your own tags and descriptions is less likely to be helpful to others than using the publicly edited tags, which are already available. Browser plugins like [Bookmark Tagging](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmarks-tagging/kmdepbjjhlbhohppiancfgdpkjcoajgb?hl=en-US) already exist, so I don't see an argument for a new feature.
3. This has [already been discussed extensively](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1569/is-there-any-way-to-favorite-bookmark-an-answer) and [the feature has been declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite-star).

Comment: The idea is that community is a reference and it should be considered like that. Every user should be arrange and manage his/her reference as possible as to be friendly for him. 
I don't know how do you understand that I want to know other users favorites. It is not true. I mean by per user, that every user could able to manage his own not others favorites.